# Adding deep learning model at django

Tags: python, django, pytorch

[image]

ml: django app folder
test: pytorch python code folder --predict.py(model)

And I wanted to use procees function that i made at predcit.py at views.py

process function

```
def process():
for img_file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\model\\project\\ml\\test\\images'):

    img_path = os.path.join('images', img_file)

    predition = predict_breed_transfer(model, img_path)
    print(predition)
    print("image_file_name: {0}, \t predition breed: {1}\n\n".format(img_path, predition))

return (predition)
```

views.py at ml folder

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .test.predict import *


def predict(request):
    pred=process()

    return render(request, "predict.html",{'pred':pred})
```

When i run the server at my local computer, it gets pred as none.
I don't understand why views.py doesn't run 'predict_breed_transfer'function...

Comment: You tried like this?  `from ml.test.predict import *`

Comment: yes... But it doesn't work.... thanks for your comment